# Quel est le sens de « faites des enfants meilleurs » ?

Tags: sens

> Si vous voulez changer la société, faites des enfants meilleurs, car
>   ce sont eux qui changeront la société avec une éducation différente,
>   basée sur le respect de tout être.

Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire « faites des enfants meilleurs » ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Meilleur* se rapporte ici aux valeurs dont l'auteur de la phrase se revendique.

L'auteur adresse par cette phrase un message aux gens, en leur demandant de faire *des enfants qui soient meilleurs dans leur comportement, et qui soient plus respectueux que ne le sont les gens vivant actuellement*.

Answer (score 2):

*Meilleur* reflète ici le sens moral de l'adjectif *bon*, comme dans *le bien* ou *le mal*.

Le sens de *faites des enfants meilleurs* est « faites en sorte que vos enfants soient bien éduqués ».