# « Tout être » ou « tout l'être » ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, déterminants

Cette question renvoie au passage suivant, qui apparait dans [une autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/quel-est-le-sens-de-faites-des-enfants-meilleurs) :

> Si vous voulez changer la société, faites des enfants meilleurs, car ce sont eux qui changeront la société avec une éducation différente, basée sur le respect de **tout être**.

Je suis au fait que « être » peut être un verbe ou un nom masculin. Ici, il semble qu'il agisse en tant que nom. À condition que ce soit vrai, pourquoi **tout être** et non pas **tout l'être** ?

Comment: Être, as a noun, means "being". "Un être humain", for example is a human being.

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit bien d'un nom masculin définissant *la qualité de ce qui est* (le petit Robert)

> - tout *être* : n'importe quel *être*.
> - tout *l'être* : l'*être* dans son entier (le soi).

---

**AJOUT** *suite au commentaire*

La remarque d’Édouard apporte des compléments à la définition (telle qu'elle est habituellement entendue) de l'*être* : « ce qui est animé et vivant, ou supposé comme tel » ou « personne, être humain » .

"*tout être*" développé en : "*tout* ce qui a *la qualité de ce qui est*" est une définition générique qui englobe les autres.
Elle pourra être lue ainsi dans des essais, dans des écrits philosophiques, mais pas dans les romans ou dans la littérature classique.

***Complément** demandé sur* les autres *:*
*les autres* êtres, avec la notion d'altérité sous-jacente : s'il y a unicité apparente d'un être manifesté (existant), sa substance même est semblable à celle des autres êtres (par l'énergie originelle du vivant et la perception d'une réalité que ces êtres partagent).

Comment: Dans « tout être », je comprends « être » comme « ce qui est animé et vivant, ou supposé comme tel » ou « personne, être humain », pas « la qualité de ce qui est ». (Le Petit Robert aussi).

Comment: @Edouard En reprenant cette définition, l'expression *un être vivant* est donc un pléonasme ?

Comment: Puisque je n’emploierais pas « être vivant » si je ne veut désigner que les « personnes, êtres humains », je penche pour le non.

Comment: @RomainVALERI ce serait une tautologie si l'*être* ne pouvait être que vivant, mais il peut être un *être* : malade, malfaisant ou bienveillant ... et même décédé lorsqu'il retrouve son néant.

Comment: @cl-r D'abord, seule une phrase peut être une tautologie, pas un simple groupe nominal. Ensuite, être malade, malfaisant ou bienveillant implique qu'on soit vivant. En revanche, un "être décédé" ? Un "ne plus être" n'est pas un être...

Comment: @RomainVALERI Il est vrai que tautologie est surtout référencé pour un discours, mais je n'ai pas vue d'exclusive le rattachant à une phrase ; *être vivant* est logiquement toujours vrai lorsque vous circonvenez l’*être* au vivant en oubliant l’opposé philosophique : *être de raison* (*objet* qui n'existe que dans la pensée) (le petit Robert fin de §) ... ce qui fait tomber le pléonasme.  *être décédé* est un clin d’œil à l’indissociabilité de l’être et du néant : rien ne se perd, rien ne se crée, tout se transforme, le néant devient un autre état de l’être, deux mots pour la même réalité :)

Comment: Il me semblait pourtant de Carnap avait tué la métaphysique. Et Heidegger avant lui. Et Nietzsche avant lui. Et Kant avant lui. Après toutes ces attaques contre son non-être, Démocrite est mal en point, laissons-le dormir ;-)

Comment: @cl-r: Quelles définitions sont **les autres** dans *"tout être" développé en : "tout ce qui a la qualité de ce qui est" est une définition générique qui englobe **les autres**.* ? Prière de riposter dans votre réponse, et non pas en tant qu'un commentaire, SVP.

Comment: @cl-r: Je vous suis reconnaissant. Puisque je reste perdu sur `les autres`, pourriez-vous expliciter votre ajout et réponse originale ?

Comment: @LePressentiment J'ai un doute sur les indications fournies par l'onglet "inbox". Est-ce que le complément apporté répond à votre questionnement? sinon, il faudrait m'indiquer pourquoi cette altérité (universelle) sous entendue dans *les autres* barre votre chemin.

Comment: @cl-r: Je vous reste connaissant. Veuillez pardonner mon questionnement diffus, car je reste embrouillé. Dans votre complément, vous amorcez avez `avec la notion d'altérité sous-jacente.` Toutefois, la prochaine phrase traite d'une `unicité apparente.` En outre, quelle est `la substance`, `l'énergie`, `le vivant`, `une réalité` ?