# Que m'importe que = Peu m'importe que ?

Tags: sens

[Cet affiche avant-dernier](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=446121&p=2575585#post2575585) allègue que **Que m'importe que** ... = *Peu m'importe que* ...

La P77 de Advanced French Grammar de V. Mazet prône ce qui suit :

> You've learned that the imperative has only three forms: tu, nous, vous. However, you may sometimes need to express a command in the third person, singular or plural, ..., or a wish made out loud. To do so, you can use ... **pourvu que** + subjunctive, or a sentence that begins directly with **Que** + subjunctive, without even an introductory verb.

Du coup, la première fois que je suis tombé sur **Que m'importe que**, je m'étais imaginé que cela voulait dire "Pourvu qu'il/Qu'il m'est important que ...". Pourtant, c'était erroné.

En conséquence, comment décortiquer, démêler, dénouer et éplucher (la genèse et la structure de) **Que m'importe que** pour dériver et parvenir à *Peu m'importe que* ?

Voici deux œuvres qui renferment cette tournure : [Celle d'Alphonse  Esquiros](http://books.google.com/books?id=D7uc8ntPYNgC&pg=PA184&dq=%22que+m%27importe+que%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=ZUxMUp3ZFKm3iQf5tIDwCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22que%20m%27importe%20que%22&f=false) 
et 
[Celle de Denis Diderot](http://books.google.com/books?id=3zIHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA460&dq=%22que+m%27importe+que%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=w0dMUsOTIMbOiAfr6oHYDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22que%20m%27importe%20que%22&f=false).

Comment: "j'avais imaginé qu'elle veut dire" je propose "je m'étais imaginé que ça voulait dire"

Comment: @Knu: Merci. Pourriez-vous expliciter votre égard/prédilection ?

Comment: Ceci mériterait une question ; à laquelle je serais incapable de répondre. Ça sonnait faux tout simplement (si l'on prend en compte le début de la phrase bien sûr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le petit Robert range sous la même explication les deux termes : dans des locutions interrogatives ou négatives qui marquent l'indifférence à l'égard d'une chose sans importance, sans conséquence.

L'académie française :

> Dans les expressions *Qu'importe* et *Peu importe*, qui servent à marquer
>   l'indifférence que l'on a ou que l'on doit avoir pour une chose, le
>   peu de cas que l'on en fait ou que l'on doit en faire.

---

Sans aucune valeur définitive, on peut essayer de faire une différence en s'accrochant aux racines de *peu* et de *que[lconque]* :

> - *peu m'importe* : il y a *peu* de choses pour lesquelles j'ai de l'indifférence (les autres "n'existent même pas").
> - *que m'importe* : quelles *que* soient les choses qui existent (dans le domaine dont on parle) cela ne m'influencera pas.

On peut ainsi envisager :

- le *peu m'importe* comme une réponse à un (ou en prévision d'un) argumentaire (une personne) que l'on juge insignifiant,
- le *que m'importe* comme un argumentaire absolu qui ignorera toute contradiction, même venue d'une personne faisant autorité dans le domaine concerné.

> - Vous dites que c'est la nouvelle lune, *peu m'importe* ces chimères astrales, ces broutilles !
> - Que m'importent les réponses du maître, je ferai ce qui est prévu, et jusqu'au bout !

Cela pourrait être une indication pour une pièce de théâtre où les intonations ne seront pas les mêmes si l'on intervertit *peu* et *que*.

Mais tout cela reste dans le domaine de l'oralité, de la subjectivité.

Comment: En bref, est-ce que ce qui suit est valable ? **peu m'importe que...** = *Little matters to me that ...* & **que m'importe que...** = *Whatever matters to me that...*. Dans le dernier, le premier que = Whatever ≠ What.

Comment: @LePressentiment De ce que j'arrive à comprendre des nuances de l'anglais, il me semble que nous sommes en phase -- Compléments apportés sur http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7598/tout-etre-ou-tout-letre/7599?noredirect=1#comment13085_7599, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/etre-bienvenu-et-etre-le-bienvenu/7644?noredirect=1#comment13082_7644

Answer (score 2):

Personnellement, je trouve la formule *Peu m'importe que* peu naturelle lorsqu'elle est suivie par un autre bout de phrase ; contrairement à *Que m'importe que*.

Je dirais donc :

> Que m'importe qu'il fasse beau ou non, j'irai jouer au tennis.

Mais pas :

> Peu m'importe qu'il fasse beau ou non, j'irai jouer au tennis.

Cependant, il me parait correct d'utiliser *Peu m'importe que* en terminant directement la phrase comme ceci :

> Peu m'importe qu'il fasse beau ou non !

Dans ce dernier cas, on peut dire que *Peu m'importe que* et *Que m'importe que* peuvent avoir le même sens :

> Peu m'importe qu'il fasse beau ou non !

aura donc le même sens que :

> Que m'importe qu'il fasse beau ou non !

Comment: Ah ah, je dirais exactement l'inverse. C'est juste une façon indirecte de dire « Qu'il fasse beau ou non, j'irais jouer au tennis ». Enfin dans cet exemple c'est même un peu maladroit sauf pour faire passer une certaine forme d'ironie : « quoi que je pense des conditions, on m'a dit d'y aller ». Utiliser le subjonctif dans une proposition seule ça ne marche pas (sauf pour un souhait avec un point d'exclamation à la fin — mais là ce n'en est pas un —, ou en tant que question, avec l'indicatif — ok dans ce cas ça ne change rien — et un point d'interrogation — mais dans ta phrase il n'y est pas).

Comment: Je suis tout à fait d'accord, j'avais échangé les 2 par inadvertance. Et j'ai ajouté les points d'interrogation que j'avais hésité à mettre.